# AngularJS ng-repeat index limit?

Tags: angularjs

is there a way to represent a value based on specific data and put a limit on it?

i wanna show only 3 value of span but this is show up 4 span.

help me

this is my example code

```
<div ng-repeat="list in checkDate">
   <span ng-if="list.day == '20200120'">{{list.time}} {{list.day}}</span>
</div>

$scope.checkDate = [{
            day: '20200120',
            time: '09:30'
        }, {
            day: '20200119',
            time: '10:30'
        }, {
            day: '20200120',
            time: '11:30'
        },
        {
            day: '20200109',
            time: '12:30'
        },
        {
            day: '20200125',
            time: '13:30'
        },
        {
            day: '20200120',
            time: '14:30'
        },
        {
            day: '20200120',
            time: '15:30'
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is why `ng-if` is inside `ng-repeat`.

So if you try with only `limitTo` it will not work.

First you have to `filter` record based on your desired date and than you have to apply `limitTo` to `ng-repeat`.

Solution - `ng-repeat="list in checkDate | filter: {day: '20200120'} | limitTo:3"`

try this - https://jsfiddle.net/qkvf2ojh/

Comment: working example https://jsfiddle.net/meetpatel9814/d6jfbuo4/3/

Comment: @MeetPatel In your example you have used `AngularJS 1.0.3`, in this version `ng-if` was not available. In the above fiddle only `limitTo` filter is working. please check

Comment: understood your problem, look for updated code https://jsfiddle.net/qkvf2ojh/

Answer (score 0):

It's because `ng-if` is applied after `limitTo` filter producing result. In this case, use `filter` instead of `ng-if` directive. For example,

```
   <div ng-repeat="list in checkDate | filter: {day: '20200120'} | limitTo:3">
       <span>{{list.time}} {{list.day}}</span>
   </div>
```

Comment: I understood your issue, just edited the answer. Please give a try.